# Delphi download file Android with Memory Stream

Tags: android, delphi, indy, delphi-xe5

I am trying to download a file from a server in this way:

```
var MeS:TMemoryStream;
begin
 Mes:=TMemoryStream.Create;
 IdFTP1.Connect;
 Mes.Position:=0;
  try
   IdFTP1.Get(Mes, 'dolcestilnovo.txt', True, False);
  finally
   MeS.Free;
   IdFTP1.Disconnect;
  end;
 Memo5.Lines.LoadFromStream(Mes);
end;
```

I must show the content of `dolcestilnovo.txt` inside that Memo5, but I have an error on the `IdFTP1.Get();` method.

The error says "There is no overloaded version of 'Get' that can be called with these parameters". What can I do?

I thought to use the `MemoryStream` since I'm downloading it on an android device.

Comment: Just a side note, you are trying to populate the memo with the contents of a freed memory stream.

Comment: How can I download that file then?

Comment: From what I can see,  Get(string,TStream,boolean) is the overload to use here.

Comment: Your `Mes.Position:=0` is pointless there. It's an empty stream!

Comment: The `Mes.Free` is also in the wrong place. You are freeing the stream before it is loaded into the Memo.

Comment: Here's a tip for you in the future: Once you type `Something.Free;`, it's almost always wrong to type `Something.` again until you create it again. Once you `Free` it, it isn't able to be used any longer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the signature of the `TStream` version of `TIdFTP.Get()`:

```
procedure Get(const ASourceFile: string; ADest: TStream; AResume: Boolean = false); overload;
```

See why your code does not match it?  Use this instead:

```
IdFTP1.Get('dolcestilnovo.txt', Mes, False);
```

And do not forget to reset the `TMemoryStream.Position` back to 0 again before calling `Memo5.Lines.LoadFromStream(Mes)` or else it will not load anything.

Try this:

```
var
  MeS: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Mes := TMemoryStream.Create;
  IdFTP1.Connect;
  try
    IdFTP1.Get('dolcestilnovo.txt', Mes, False);
  finally
    IdFTP1.Disconnect;
  end;
  Mes.Position := 0;
  Memo5.Lines.LoadFromStream(Mes);
end;
```

Comment: so when I end the try-catch statement I put a Mes.Position:=0 ?

Comment: Doesn't the memory stream have to be free'd?

Comment: @JerryDodge, ARC is implemented on the Android platform. No need to free objects. Confusing, yes I know and will mess up many code snippets in the future since it invalidates almost two decades of code.